# Google Maps API "Custom Popups" Example Code Breaks in VueJS Single File Components

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a custom Google Maps popup as per the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup).

When I copy/paste the official Google example code into a VueJS jsFiddle, the custom marker behaves exactly as expected. That is, when you pan across the map, the marker stays in the correct location. [Here is the jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phao5814/eywraw8t/215503/).

**"Hello this is me" will always stay in its original position regardless of where you pan. This is the desired behaviour.**

[image]

However, when I copy/paste the code into a VueJS single file component, the marker doesn't stay in the correct position. **That is, the marker is always displayed in the centre of the entire map no matter where I pan (as shown below). Additionally, the styling of the Popup becomes completely broken as well. [Here is the sandbox demonstrating the problem. (Refer to HelloWorld.vue component)](https://codesandbox.io/s/74oylzrq36)**

[image]

Below is the  code in my Single File Component (it is virtually identicaly to the jsFiddle above).

**Is there a reason for why I'm getting inconsistent results and how can I amend the Single File Component so that it yields the same effect as the jsFiddle?**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="content">
            Hello this is me
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                map: "",
                popup: "",
                Popup: "",
            };
        },
        methods: {
            definePopupClass() {
                /**
                * A customized popup on the map.
                * @param {!google.maps.LatLng} position
                * @param {!Element} content
                * @constructor
                * @extends {google.maps.OverlayView}
                */
                this.Popup = function(position, content) {
                    this.position = position;

                    content.classList.add('popup-bubble-content');

                    var pixelOffset = document.createElement('div');
                    pixelOffset.classList.add('popup-bubble-anchor');
                    pixelOffset.appendChild(content);

                    this.anchor = document.createElement('div');
                    this.anchor.classList.add('popup-tip-anchor');
                    this.anchor.appendChild(pixelOffset);

                    // Optionally stop clicks, etc., from bubbling up to the map.
                    this.stopEventPropagation();
                };
                // NOTE: google.maps.OverlayView is only defined once the Maps API has
                // loaded. That is why Popup is defined inside initMap().
                this.Popup.prototype = Object.create(google.maps.OverlayView.prototype);

                /** Called when the popup is added to the map. */
                this.Popup.prototype.onAdd = function() {
                    this.getPanes().floatPane.appendChild(this.anchor);
                };

                /** Called when the popup is removed from the map. */
                this.Popup.prototype.onRemove = function() {
                    if (this.anchor.parentElement) {
                        this.anchor.parentElement.removeChild(this.anchor);
                    }
                };

                /** Called when the popup needs to draw itself. */
                this.Popup.prototype.draw = function() {
                    var divPosition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.position);
                    // Hide the popup when it is far out of view.
                    var display =
                    Math.abs(divPosition.x) < 4000 && Math.abs(divPosition.y) < 4000 ?
                    'block' :
                    'none';

                    if (display === 'block') {
                        this.anchor.style.left = divPosition.x + 'px';
                        this.anchor.style.top = divPosition.y + 'px';
                    }
                    if (this.anchor.style.display !== display) {
                        this.anchor.style.display = display;
                    }
                };

                /** Stops clicks/drags from bubbling up to the map. */
                this.Popup.prototype.stopEventPropagation = function() {
                    var anchor = this.anchor;
                    anchor.style.cursor = 'auto';

                    ['click', 'dblclick', 'contextmenu', 'wheel', 'mousedown', 'touchstart',
                    'pointerdown']
                    .forEach(function(event) {
                        anchor.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
                            e.stopPropagation();
                        });
                    });
                };
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.definePopupClass();
                this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: {lat: -33.9, lng: 151.1},
                    zoom: 10,
                });

                this.popup = new this.Popup(
                    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.866, 151.196),
                    document.getElementById('content'));
                this.popup.setMap(this.map);
            });
        }
    };
</script>

<style scoped>

    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
    * element that contains the map. */
    #map {
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    /* The location pointed to by the popup tip. */
    .popup-tip-anchor {
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        /* The max width of the info window. */
        width: 200px;
    }
    /* The bubble is anchored above the tip. */
    .popup-bubble-anchor {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: /* TIP_HEIGHT= */ 8px;
        left: 0;
    }
    /* Draw the tip. */
    .popup-bubble-anchor::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: -1px;
        left: 0;
        /* Center the tip horizontally. */
        transform: translate(-50%, 0);
        /* The tip is a https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ */
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        /* The tip is 8px high, and 12px wide. */
        border-left: 6px solid transparent;
        border-right: 6px solid transparent;
        border-top: /* TIP_HEIGHT= */ 8px solid white;
    }
    /* The popup bubble itself. */
    .popup-bubble-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
        /* Style the info window. */
        background-color: white;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        overflow-y: auto;
        max-height: 60px;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem exists since I'm using scoped style in the Single File Component example. Removing the scoped attribute from the style tag resolves the issue.

Comment: The same issue can be reproduced when integrating the Google Maps in Angular. Changing the `encapsulationView` to `None` resolved the case.