# Google maps custom popups keeps moving

Tags: typescript, google-maps

Ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup#maps_overlay_popup-typescript

I am trying to display a custom popup on google maps, but the popup keeps redrawing itself back to it's original position when I move the map. How can I force it to stay where it's meant to?

Below is the code copied almost verbatim from Google docs. This method is within a Vue component:

```
loadCustomPopup () {
  /**
   * A customized popup on the map.
   */
  class Popup extends window.google.maps.OverlayView {
    position: any;
    containerDiv: HTMLElement;

    constructor (position: any, content: HTMLElement) {
      super();
      this.position = position;

      content.classList.add('popup-bubble');

      // This zero-height div is positioned at the bottom of the bubble.
      const bubbleAnchor = document.createElement('div');

      bubbleAnchor.classList.add('popup-bubble-anchor');
      bubbleAnchor.appendChild(content);

      // This zero-height div is positioned at the bottom of the tip.
      this.containerDiv = document.createElement('div');
      this.containerDiv.classList.add('popup-container');
      this.containerDiv.appendChild(bubbleAnchor);

      // Optionally stop clicks, etc., from bubbling up to the map.
      Popup.preventMapHitsAndGesturesFrom(this.containerDiv);
    }

    /** Called when the popup is added to the map. */
    onAdd () {
      this.getPanes()!.floatPane.appendChild(this.containerDiv);
    }

    /** Called when the popup is removed from the map. */
    onRemove () {
      if (this.containerDiv.parentElement) {
        this.containerDiv.parentElement.removeChild(this.containerDiv);
      }
    }

    /** Called each frame when the popup needs to draw itself. */
    draw () {
      const divPosition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(
        this.position
      )!;

      // Hide the popup when it is far out of view.
      const display =
        Math.abs(divPosition.x) < 4000 && Math.abs(divPosition.y) < 4000
          ? 'block'
          : 'none';

      if (display === 'block') {
        this.containerDiv.style.left = divPosition.x + 'px';
        this.containerDiv.style.top = divPosition.y + 'px';
      }

      if (this.containerDiv.style.display !== display) {
        this.containerDiv.style.display = display;
      }
    }
  }

  return Popup;
}
```

Here is how I'm calling it. Another method within the Vue component :

```
loadMarkerInfoWindow (marker) {
  window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', async () => {
    const lat = marker.position.lat();
    const lng = marker.position.lng();
    const LatLng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    this.map.panTo(LatLng);

    const popupClass = this.loadCustomPopup();
    const popup = new popupClass(
      LatLng,
      this.$refs.googleMapsCustomPopup
    );
    popup.setMap(this.map);
    this.injectItemCardToInfoWindow(marker.item);
  });
}
```

The `injectItemCardToInfoWindow()` function pulls in a vue component to load in the popup. The problem with the popup redrawing itself happens whether I use the vue component or just some hard coded html.

The result I'm getting is that the custom popup appears on the page in roughly the right location to start with. But as I move around the map the popup redraws itself back to it's original position. To elaborate:
When the popup appears it is in position x,y in relation to the frame of the map. When I pan/zoom the map the popup moves with it as expected fixed over where it was drawn. However, when I mouseup or finish zooming the popup then redraws itself back to x,y in relation to the frame of the map.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "popup keeps moving with the map"?

Comment: @jpoehnelt When the popup appears it is in position x,y in relation to the frame of the map. When I pan/zoom the map the popup moves with it as expected fixed over where it was drawn. However, when I mouseup or finish zooming the popup then redraws itself back to x,y in relation to the frame of the map.

Comment: @joe92 I'm running into the same issue when I'm trying to integrate the GoogleMaps in Angular. Have you found any solution since the post has been created? Running the original code in a plain HTML file with <script> injected googlemapsapi-js-file works fine, but in Angular the custom-popup redraw itself to tits original position (the position it first was drawed).

Comment: As someone pointed elsewhere, the scoped style / encapsulation view style might be the problem. Changed the EncapsulationView to `None` resolved the issue. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51569798/google-maps-api-custom-popups-example-code-breaks-in-vuejs-single-file-compone?rq=1

Comment: @PianoSong I didn't get anywhere with it and gave up due to time constraints. Instead I forced the default InfoWindow to work to my requirements instead. It wasn't as good looking but it got the feature out the door. Thank you for the comment and link to answer. I may be able to revisit this in the future and fix it properly now.